# How to get strategy capital at previous bar's close

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Using Pine Script within Trading View, I'm trying to get my strategy's closing capital on the previous bar's close as such:

```
lastBarCapital = strategy.equity[1]
```

Will this give me my strategy's capital at yesterday's bar's Close, Open, High, or Low?

Certainly, the capital changes throughout the day - but I'm interested in knowing what it is at on the previous bar's Close.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no open positions, it is the same value for open, high, low or close. So, you can consider it as the equity at the close of the candle.

If the position is open, it will still be the equity at the close of the candle. This is mainly because

```
strategy.equity = strategy.initial_capital + strategy.netprofit + strategy.openprofit
```

where 'strategy.openprofit' is unrealized profit, thus the unrealized profit at the previous candle close.

Answer (score 0):

All the historical values (e.g. volume, strategy.equity, sma etc.) will reflect the value at close. The OHLC information is only available for price.

So, `strategy.equity[1]` will return you your capital at the preceding bar - might not be "yesterday" if you are not on the daily timeframe.